# Git - How to force pull from an upstream remote and ignore commits in your local and remote?

Tags: git, github

I want to pull from from an upstream branch and I want to ignore all commits made by me in my local and my remote on git. I only want the changes from the upstream remote.

I am having issues with:

```
git pull upstream master
```

And I do not want to manually merge them. I just want to ignore all my local changes and the above command to work.

I tried:

```
git reset --hard
```

But that doesn't seem to work for me. I want the changes from the upstream.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You need to specify the remote name because it is equal to `origin` by default

```
git reset --hard upstream/master
```

Comment: You should explain what that does and why it answers the question.

Comment: Wow! That worked. Thanks a lot :). But yes, a little more explanation on how exactly it does it would be even more helpful!

Comment: This is useful. Reset is equivalent to checking out those branches. It brings the head to the upstream's branch state.

Comment: Saved my day!
Local changes were deleted and local master now has the upstream changes,

Comment: I tried this, got `fatal: ambiguous argument 'upstream/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree. Use '--' to separate paths from revisions:`, so I edited to `git reset --hard origin/master` and it worked!

Comment: I should add that nowadays many repo's the main branch is called `main` and not `master`. So in that case, you might have to do: 

`git reset --hard upstream/main`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve this which I have now found is, you can remove all changes in your branch with

`git checkout .`

Once your branch is clean, you can checkout another branch with:

`git checkout <anotherbranchname>`

Now you can delete the old branch locally by running:

`git branch -d <branchtoremovelocalchanges>`

Now you can go to that branch again with:

`git checkout <branchtoremovelocalchanges>`

and now you will see everything the way it is on the server. I know this is a more roundabout way of achieving what the first answer suggests, but its another option.